# Rabbit MQ plugin .ez not generated

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

I clone the repository [1] and modify rabbitmq_management plugin by adding new function for my use. All the code changes completed and tested using make `run-broker`. Now I need to generate executable file. I followed [2] for plugin development and try with `make dist`. It is completed without any error. Plugins folder created and there are sub folders for each plugin. But .ez file not available in anywhere.

What is the mistake.

[1]. https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server

[2]. https://www.rabbitmq.com/plugin-development.html

Answer (score 0):

Following answer getting to git discussion is working properly [1].

[1]. https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions/5246#discussioncomment-3170511